# How to run single test file in jest puppeteer e2e testing?

Tags: angular, jest-puppeteer

I am new to puppeteer automation testing, Can anyone please tell me how to execute only one test file.

Answer (score 1):

Please look at

https://github.com/AaronWatters/hello_jest

For an example of how to set up Jest with Puppeteer to test some Javascript code.  It is intended to be a documented relatively simple "hello world" example.